# ASP page hit counter

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please tell me basic steps for coding and server coding and steps of server connection for Simple page hit counter using asp C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? go for one of the free web analytics tools available..

Comment: Like Abdel Olakara already said: why reinvent. I use www.statcounter.com all the time. It is free and gives a lot of information

Comment: Or if you're interested in more than just the hit counter, you can utilize Google Analytics http://www.google.com/analytics/ to get information like how long users were on a page, etc..

Comment: Most of the 3rd party sites (including Google Analytics) only work if the client has JavaScript enabled - that doesn't include a lot of robots, older browsers, some embedded devices, etc. Stats on those clients are important for a lot of applications.

Answer (score 1):

An Idea: When the page loads, increment the count for that page, saved in a database table or file.

Answer (score 1):

Some source code and examples for make a page hit counter.
Some of them are old, and I just place them here just for a good "where to start" ideas for a page hit counter.

http://www.asp101.com/samples/counter_db_aspx.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ewcounter.aspx

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Hit-Counter-for-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: Re your first link, the author says in the comments: "This article was good in its time, but things have come a long way since 2003 when I wrote this article. Storing the value of a counter in a file is considered to be poor style, as is using cookies to identify and track users. ASP.NET has changed so much that guerrilla techniques like this are unnecessary."

Comment: @Basiclife thank you for the notice, I will change it, just I think that is a good start to think some ways to make what is looking for, and not actually the best way to do it.

Comment: agreed. The only reason I bothered to check it is that storing the count in a file often results in access violation errors as file operations are slow = an increased risk of threading issues - When I found the comment, I thought I'd add it. In any case, I take your point about being examples only :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application["UserCount"] = 0;  
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application["UserCount"] = Convert.ToInt32( Application["UserCount"].ToString()) + 1;
Application.UnLock();
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application["UserCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["UserCount"].ToString()) - 1;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when the app pool recycles? Or if this is in a web farm?